# Check to see if CallResponder is processing

Tags: apache-flex, asynchronous

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6. As a simple example, say I have the following application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:sdk="services.sdk.*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function btnGetValue_clickHandler():void
            {
                getValueResult.token = sdk.getValue();
            }

            private function getValueResultHandler():void
            {
                // ...
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <sdk:SDK id="sdk" fault="{Alert.show(event.fault.faultString +'\n\n'+ event.fault.faultDetail, 'SDK ERROR');}" showBusyCursor="false"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="getValueResult" result="getValueResultHandler()"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button id="btnGetValue" click="btnGetValue_clickHandler()" label="Get Value" />
</s:Application>
```

So when you click on the button, it calls a PHP file and when it gets a result, it calls `getValueResultHandler()`. Easy enough.

But what if the response from the PHP file takes a second or two and the user clicks the button rapidly? Then the result handler function may not get called every time, since the call responder gets a new token before it received the last response.

Is there a standard way of resolving this issue? I came up with the following workaround, and it works fine, but it seems like this issue would be common enough to have a more built-in solution.

My workaround is:

```
var getValueResultProcessing:Boolean = false;

private function btnGetValue_clickHandler():void
{
    var interval:uint = setInterval(function():void
    {
        if (!getValueResultProcessing)
        {
            getValueResultProcessing = true;
            getValueResult.token = sdk.getValue();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
    getValueResult.token = sdk.getValue();
}

private function getValueResultHandler():void
{
    getValueResultProcessing = false;
    // ...
}
```

Any better way of resolving this issue?

---

**EDIT:**

One of my actual scenarios for which I need a solution is when looping:

```
private function btnGetValue_clickHandler():void
{
    var arr:Array = new Array("value1", "value2", "value3");
    for each (var value:String in arr)
        getValueResult.token = sdk.getValue(value);
}
```

So to solve this problem I make `arr` a global variable and use the `setInterval` method I described before to `shift` off the first element and then do the same exact thing in the result function until `arr` is empty.

Again, looking for a more "standard" solution, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `CallResponder`, you might want to manage the responses to service calls yourself. HTTPService (or similar Flex services) return an `AsyncToken` when you call the `HTTPService.send()` method. You can then add 'result' and 'fault' handlers by using the `AsyncToken.addResponder()` method.

If you do it this way, each responder will trigger it's result or fault handler as appropriate. Then use the last approach as suggest by Sam DeHaan, where you store each token in an array when the call is made, and remove the token from the array when the 'result' or 'fault' handler is executed. When removing a token from the array, you can re-enable the button if the array is empty.

You do it something like this (typing code from memory):

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
// configure the service...
var token:AsyncToken = service.send();
// resultHandlerMethod and faultHandler method are functions that you should define
// their signatures look like this:
// resultHandlerMethod(event:ResultEvent)
// faultHandlerMethod(event:FaultEvent)
token.addResponder(new Responder(resultHandlerMethod, faultHandlerMethod);
```

Comment: I considered doing something similar to this, by creating an array of CallResponders via Actionscript, but how does the result handler method know which token (which entry in the array) called it? I don't think I can rely on each call returning in the same order that they were called.

Comment: That's exactly what the AsyncToken does. It guarantees that the call you make will be handled only by the result/fault handlers that you assign it (via the `addResponder()` method :)

Comment: Here's an [article from Adobe's Flex Cookbook](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Tracking_results_from_multiple_simultaneous_servic-922.html) that discusses this in detail.

Comment: Sounds like that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the call is button based, disable the button on click. Enable the button at the end of the callback. Simple.

Comment: I updated my question. This solution doesn't work for me when I make the calls in a loop.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, I would do them serially, and re-enable the button when the array of items is empty. However, if you want to do them in parallel, I don't have a great solution for you off the top of my head.